# Is the discordjs documentation complete? (v12.2)

Tags: discord.js

I'm looking at the Discord.JS docs, specifically the `Channel` documentation, located here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.2.0/class/Channel and I can't see any reference to `Message` which is accessible from this object.

In my working code I have:

```
const discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new discordjs.Client()
...
client.channels.cache.get(channelId)
await channel.messages.fetch()
```

My code is using v12.2.0 as defined in the `package.json` and `yarn.lock`.

```
"discord.js": "^12.2.0",
```

My code works, but I can't see the matching methods and fields available in the documentation. Am I reading the documentation wrong or is it incomplete?

Comment: The message is accessible through the [message event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message) or by fetching a message from [MessageManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Channel` is a general class, `TextChannel` and `VoiceChannel` are derived from it. Since VCs obviously don't have any messages, only TextChannel Objects have a messages property.

If you want more clearness about which specific type is used when, I'd suggest you to use TypeScript, really works well with Discord.js